# Series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(3n + k)!}x^{3n + k}, \ k = 0, 1, 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, summation

Everyone knows that $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ for any complex argument $\theta$, and that the Maclaurin series expansion of say $\sin(z)$ is given by:

$$
\sin(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n x^{2n+k}}{(2n+k)!}
$$

with $k = 1$, and similarly $\cos(x)$ with $k = 0$.

So what happens when you consider summing over all residues in a coset of $3\Bbb{Z}$ instead?

Substituting in $ix$ for the $3\Bbb{Z}$ case we gives us:

$$
f_0(ix) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{i^n x^{3n}}{(3n)!} \\
f_1(ix) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{i^{n+1} x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!} \\
f_2(ix) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{i^{n+2} x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!} \\
$$

So that $f_0(ix) + f_1(ix) + f_2(ix) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (\dfrac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} + i\dfrac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!} - \dfrac{x^{3n+2}}{(3n+2)!})i^n$.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha uses only $e^x , \cos x, \sin x$ to evaluate these summations so it seems that any generalization will also have a closed-form using $e^x , \cos x, \sin x$.

Comment: For $k=0$ it should be equal to something like $\frac{1}{3} (e^x + e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^2 x})$ where $\omega = e^{\pi i/3} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$ is a primitive sixth root of 1.  And similarly for $k=1$, $\frac{1}{3} (e^x + \omega^{-1} e^{\omega x} + \omega^{-2} e^{\omega^2 x})$, and yet another similar formula for $k=2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler those are not all in the same formula like Euler's.

Comment: It looks like the formula for $k=0$ should actually be: $\frac{1}{3} (e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^3 x} + e^{\omega^5 x}) = \frac{1}{3} (e^{-x} + 2 e^{x/2} \cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x))$.

Comment: For another approach of how you'd get these expressions: all three are solutions to the differential equation $y''' + y = 0$.  What are the roots of the characteristic equation $r^3 + 1 = 0$?  (Then the three just give different initial conditions for $y(0), y'(0), y''(0)$.)

Comment: Also you can consider that taking the derivative / integral you decrease increase $k$, so they are related in the same way as sin/cos

Comment: Have a look at page 10 of these notes - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view - this is a classical example for the application of a discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: The magic word is "Multisection". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection

Comment: As marty said : series multisection and taking derivatives and integrals are key to such things.